# Unable to pull/push/clone using GIT on bitbucket anymore

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push, git-pull, git-clone

Although I cloned a repository before, but now whenever I try to use push, pull or even clone the repository again, it asks for the password, I provide it then i do not get any sort of feedback for a LOT of time.. Although I did clone that same repository before, now none of the above commands work.

What could be the reason for this problem? it doesn't even tell me anything if i enter a wrong password..

Comment: Did you have your router block the URL?

Comment: I've had similar symptoms after changing my `ssh`/`rsa` key: I forgot to upload the new public key to Bitbucket. Maybe you did the same, or you're now working with another PC that doesn't use the same `rsa` keyset?

Comment: I didn't change anything, I don't think this would make me unable to clone right? 
in fact, i never provided my rsa key to bitbucket in the first place.. i tried adding it now but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using HTTPS and not SSH, once I added my `rsa` key on bitbucket, I cloned again using SSH, now I can push normally.

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason behind a ssh connexion asking for a password is that SSH doesn't find anymore your public/private keys.

Since you haven't changed anything, it is possible that in your current shell session (DOS or msysgit bash for Windows, for instance), you haven't defined HOME.

For a DOS session

```
set HOME=C:\Users\username
```

For a msysgit bash session

```
set HOME=/C/Users/username
```

The other reason is when your private key is protected by a passphrase, and your agent isn't running.
Atlassian has all the details regarding [Git on BitBucket and SSH](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git).